# Android : java.lang.SecurityException: Licensing.allow() has to be called first

Tags: android

Hi im developing an application to play locally encrypted video. Im using the libeasy library http://libeasy.alwaysdata.net/ to create a local server to stream the videos. When im creating an instance of the server i get this exception : java.lang.SecurityException: Licensing.allow() has to be called first. I did not found any post in google with that exception. Somebody can explain how to correct this exception?

Im running Android 4.1.1

This is my code :

```
private void myPlay(String path) {
    try {
        mServer = new LocalSingleHttpServer();
        //mServer.setCipher(myGetCipher());
        mServer.start();
        path = mServer.getURL(path);
        Log.d("", "VIDEO PATH : "+path);
        vView.setVideoPath(path);
        vView.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, the library needs a token to function. This token can be found in http://libeasy.alwaysdata.net/license/ and needs to be placed inside the application definition in your manifiest file.

```
<manifest ... >
  <application ... >
    <activity ... > </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="fr.maxcom.libmedia.apiKey" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what is answered above, you need to place the call Licensing.allow(Context) in your onCreate() method before calling the method myPlay(path).